# Public/private key alike system in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, encryption

For my autologin script I was thinking about implementing the following:

- the user gets some sort of personal "public key" that is stored in a cookie
- because I don't want to save the exact same key in my database I want to create a matching "private key"
- when the cookie is detected, the key stored in the database  is retrieved and the public/private relation is checked between the 2 keys

What is the best way to implement this in php without openSSL etc.

This is what I have now:

```
$public = hash($hash_algorithm, uniqid(rand()));
$private = hash_hmac($hash_algorithm, $public, $encryption_key);
```

And to validate:

```
$check = hash_hmac($hash_algorithm, $public, $encryption_key);
return $check == $private;
```

$encryption_key is a random key from a config file.

Am I thinking about this too simple or is this good enough? Of course when the key is used, a new one is generated like the principle here: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Comment: Can i ask why you dont want to use openssl?

Comment: Is openssl available by default? I want this script to run without having to install anything else.

Comment: No, but is very common and you can expect it on any hosting server. If there is no openssl - you can change hosting company. EDIT: Just checked with phpinfo() my few servers in diffrent hosting companies and all of them support openssl.

Comment: This is very obviously vulnerable to replay attacks. Crypto is hard to get right, and replacing a asymmetric algorithm with one that only employs symmetric algorithms is likely impossible. In other words, don't go there. Use e.g. SSL and a cookie instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is strictly *possible* to create a public-key cryptography system that only uses symmetric-key cryptography primitives (see: [SPHINCS](https://sphincs.cr.yp.to/)), you probably shouldn't roll your own design and expect it to be secure here.

> What is the best way to implement this in php without openSSL etc.

In 2018, the answer is: "with [libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use#crypto-sign)". But when you asked this question, that wasn't really an option.

But in the spirit of the question: **Outside cryptography libraries that provide asymmetric cryptography for you, or reinventing the wheel, there is no solution.**